# Julia: Expected Vector{Array{Float32}}, got a value of type Vector{Vector{Float32}}

Tags: arrays, function, vector, types, julia

I have a function `g` that takes in a Vector of Float32 Arrays as input. However, when I call the function as follows, I get an error saying that no method matching `g(::Vector{Vector{Float32}})` was found:

Code:

```
function g(x::Array{Array{Float32}, 1})
    return x
end

function f()
    a = [[1f0], [2f0]]
    println( g(a) )
end
```

Error:

```
MethodError: no method matching g(::Vector{Vector{Float32}})
  Closest candidates are:
    g(::Vector{Array{Float32}}) at ~/.../runtests.jl:25
```

How do I let `g` take in as input a vector of arbitrarily sized Float32 arrays, including 1D arrays (vectors)? I'm new to Julia, so thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x::Array{Array{Float32}, 1}` is different from `x::Array{Array{Float32, 1}, 1}` — that is, you are saying that your argument is an array of *arbitrary*-dimension arrays, which is a specific type and is different from an array of *1d* arrays.

You maybe want

```
function g(x::Array{<:Array{Float32}, 1})
```

or equivalently

```
function g(x::Vector{<:Array{Float32}})
```

or more generally (for example):

```
function g(x::AbstractVector{<:AbstractArray{<:Real}})
```

to accept any type of 1d array (any subtype of `AbstractVector`) whose elements are any type of any-dimensional array of any type of real number.

See the [Julia FAQ on invariant types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#Troubleshooting-%22method-not-matched%22:-parametric-type-invariance-and-MethodErrors).

See also the [Julia manual on argument-type declarations](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Argument-type-declarations).  There is generally zero (nada, none, zip) performance advantage to declaring a function with a type signature as specific as `g(x::Array{Array{Float32, 1}, 1})`, and it's almost certainly less general than necessary.